# how to use java stringtokenizer?

Tags: java

how to use java stringtokenizer for the below string

|feild1|field2||field4|...

i want java to take the blank as a field too, but stringtokenizer is skipping it.

Any option to get it?.

Comment: I ma using pipe symbol |

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you really need a Tokenizer?
Why not split the string to an array? This way you will have the empty fields too.

```
String fields = "bla1|bla2||bla3|bla4|||bla5";
String[] field = fields.split("\\|"); // escape the | because split() needs a regexp
```

Comment: Note that this will ignore trailing blank fields (i.e. "bla5||" returns `new String[] {"bla5"}`

Comment: @Aaron Digulla: this can be fixed. Use .split("\\|", -1) to get trailing blank fields

Answer (score 14):

What about [java.util.Scanner](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)? Much more powerful than the StringTokenizer, introduced in Java 5 and mostly unknown or underrated:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("1|2|3|||6|");
scanner.useDelimiter("\\|");
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
}
```

**EDIT:**
It can even parse the ints (and other types) directly, like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("1|2|3|||6|");
scanner.useDelimiter("\\|");
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    int x = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Comment: Definitely unknown to me and underrated. Thanks.

Comment: Year 2012, and its still unpopular! Never knew it existed!

Answer (score 3):

Without StringTokenizer using [String.split()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
for (String a : "|1|2||3|".split("\\|")) {
    System.out.println("t="+a);
}
```

Update: forgot the escaping (as usual). +1 vote.

Comment: You will need to escape the `|`.